# Find the value inside the array of objects that include children from the array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have array of objects that include children from the array of objects and i need to find value inside parent array or find value inside childrens of this array etc. Maybe recursive. I trided like this:

```js
var array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'value',
    children: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'my value',
    children: [
      {
        id: 'child1',
        value: 'my value',
        children: null
      },
      {
        id: 'child2',
        value: 'value',
        children: null
      },
      {
        id: 'child3',
        value: 'value,
        children: [
          {
            id: 'childchild1',
            value: 'my value',
            children: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: 'value',
    children: null
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    value: 'my value',
    children: null
  }
]


function find(searchData, target){
  return target.filter((f)=>{
    if(f.value.includes(searchData)){
      return true
    }
    if(f.children){
      return find(searchData, f.children)
    }
  })
}

find('my', array)
```

It's returns source array but i need array which includes text 'my'

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, but not childrens

Comment: Please include the desired output for the example you have given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a nested structure, you can't use `.filter` to get all nested objects - `.filter` will only return to you the matching objects on the topmost level. Instead, define an empty array on the initial call, then `push` to that array when an item passes the test, and pass the array around to each recursive call. Finally, return that array:

```js
var array=[{id:1,value:'value',children:null},{id:2,value:'my value',children:[{id:'child1',value:'my value',children:null},{id:'child2',value:'value',children:null},{id:'child3',value:'value',children:[{id:'childchild1',value:'my value',children:null}]}]},{id:3,value:'value',children:null},{id:4,value:'my value'}];

function find(searchData, target, accum=[]){
  target.forEach((f)=>{
    if(f.children){
      find(searchData, f.children, accum)
    }
    if(f.value.includes(searchData)){
      accum.push(f);
    }
  });
  return accum;
}

console.log(find('my', array));
```

(result is probably seen more easily via browser console than via stack snippet console)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a *functional programming* style implementation. For simplifying the output I just collected the `id` values of the matches. If you want the whole object, then replace `obj.id` by `obj`:

```js
const array = [{id: 1,value: 'value',children: null},{id: 2,value: 'my value',children: [{id: 'child1',value: 'my value',children: null},{id: 'child2',value: 'value',children: null},{id: 'child3',value: 'value' ,children: [{id: 'childchild1',value: 'my value',children: null}]}]},{id: 3,value: 'value',children: null},{id: 4,value: 'my value'}];

const find = (searchData, target) => (target || []).reduce(
        (acc, obj) => acc.concat(obj.value.includes(searchData) ? obj.id : [],
                                 find(searchData, obj.children)),
        []
    );

const result = find('my', array);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, it's very nice and short code. I have to more practice

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit too late, here is another recursive find:

```js
var array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'value',
    children: null,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'my value',
    children: [
      {
        id: 'child1',
        value: 'my value',
        children: null,
      },
      {
        id: 'child2',
        value: 'value',
        children: null,
      },
      {
        id: 'child3',
        value: 'value',
        children: [
          {
            id: 'childchild1',
            value: 'my value',
            children: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: 'value',
    children: null,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    value: 'my value',
  },
];

function find(search, arr) {
  function recur(result, search, arr) {
    if (!(arr && arr.length)) {
      return result;
    }
    return result
      .concat(
        ...arr.filter((item) =>
          item.value.includes(search),
        ),
      )
      .concat(
        ...arr.map((item) =>
          recur([], search, item.children),
        ),
      );
  }
  return recur([], search, arr);
}
console.log(find('my', array));
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but more longer code. But thanks anyway :)